# How should this site's general chat room be named?

Tags: discussion

*Interpersonal Skills* General discussion for interpersonal.stackexchange.com is quite boring... so:

How should our main chat room be named? It is custom to use a clever play of words on the topic of the site.

Comment: @Zizouz212 make it an answer to make people vote on it.

Comment: Haha, I think people would just be fondly annoyed with me and push me out :P

Comment: Possibly but quite (un)likely :-P

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### The Awkward Silence.

Because we all have no interpersonal skills and don't know what to say to each other.

Comment: That's a good one.

Comment: OMG I absolutely love this!

Comment: But, silence is golden, not awkward!

Comment: As the one who asked the first question about it, I'd love this name!

Comment: This will be unfortunate when it goes super quiet!

Comment: @Tim s/unfortunate/hilarious :-)

Comment: wow that's a good suggestion and I will even say the only good one rigth now

Comment: I wonder what percentage of people answering questions here would describe themselves as socially awkward...

Answer (score 2):

**Wallflower Garden**

Wallflower: a shy or excluded person at a dance or party, especially a girl without a partner.

Answer (score 2):

### The Relation Ship

Comment: Ahh, clever play of words, here we go.

Answer (score -4):

***The Living Room***

You are at home here. It's a friendly place where you sip your tea/coffee and discuss the ideas of the day. It's about living.

Answer (score -4):

How about

## The Telephone

People use telephones to communicate with other. It's not a physical interaction but it's still communicating with others.

Answer (score -6):

## The Friendly Chat.

Because we are communicating with each other in a friendly way.

Answer (score -7):

### The Safe Space.

Where you can talk to people without worrying about your interpersonal skills.

Comment: Nah, it may have a terrible impression, knowing how many people misinterpret the word. I strongly discourage it personally.

Answer (score -13):

## Freud's Couch

Tell others what you are thinking about.

Comment: Oh no. We're not psychologists here, are we?

Answer (score -13):

### Asperger's Syndrome

> A developmental disorder characterized by significant difficulties in social interaction and nonverbal communication.<sup>[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome)</sup>

---

> The diagnosis is everywhere: Facebook’s former head of engineering has stated that Mark Zuckerberg has “a touch of the Asperger’s.” Time suggested that the intensely awkward Bill Gates is autistic; a biographer of Warren Buffett wrote that the Oracle of Omaha, with his prodigious memory and “fascination with numbers,” has “a vaguely autistic aura.” On Celebrity Rehab, Dr. Drew Pinsky deemed Dennis Rodman (selectively hyperfocused, socially obtuse) a candidate for an Asperger’s diagnosis, and the UCLA specialist brought in to make it official “seemed to concur,” Pinsky told viewers. On the Asperger’s community site Wrong Planet, threads like “Real life celebrities who have or probably have Asperger’s” include Jim Carrey, Adolf Hitler, Daryl Hannah, Slash, Billy Joel, J. K. Rowling, and Adam Carolla, who makes the cut because “I’ve heard guests on his podcast remark on his lack of eye contact.” “Kanye Probably Has Asperger’s,” BuzzFeed recently declared.

To summarize, a majority of people could have a touch of the Asperger’s or spectrum of autism due to lack of interpersonal communication skills.

See: [Autism Spectrum: Are You On It?](http://nymag.com/news/features/autism-spectrum-2012-11/)

Comment: This implies to me that we primarily deal with Asperger's or something.

Comment: -10 Eeeh.. NOPE....

Comment: I think the name "The Awkward Silence" gets the point across better and is less likely to be taken the wrong way, or offend others.