# Chat room title

Tags: discussion, chat

Friends(?),

The main chat room for this site might be more appropriately named "The Awkward Outburst."

I know it won't be renamed but please consider what i'm trying to type.

Signed -- tied for the most awkward latencies that lead to the most awkward outbursts.

Comment: It's not really clear to me why you think the name needs to be changed at all--and it seems like the only case you make for that is saying it's more appropriately named "The Awkward Outburst." What do you mean by that? Can you elaborate on why you think the name needs to be changed?

Comment: Thank you for noticing and asking, @scohe001!  I should know better but this "question" is meant as food for throught.  What i was reflecting is how forthcoming are contributors here.  Far from "silence."  Signed, one who can't speak with open eyes or type without editing.

Comment: I'm confused, you want to rename it into "outburst", but "forthcoming" seems rather positive to me. Are you unhappy with your chatting experience? We've talked a lot about what "the Awkward Silence" is about and its policy (which actually is pretty much the same as any other SE chat room), but we do remain available if you have concerns or issues to express.

Comment: The name was chosen ([by me, oddly enough](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21/25)) to be deliberately ironic.

Comment: Still, "awkward" means "awkward." I personify that while appreciating the irony.

Comment: The name is intended to be ironic. If we wanted "silence" the chatroom wouldn't even exist :p you can chat on there and every chat on the whole SE community and policies are more or less the same.

Answer (score 6):

As Rand al'Thor [mentioned](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/chat-room-title#comment12806_3813), the name is intended to be ironic.

If you didn't have interpersonal skills, you wouldn't know [what to say to other persons](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21/12962) so it would be a "awkward silence".

If we wanted "silence" the chatroom wouldn't even exist :p. You can chat on there and every chat on the whole SE community and policies are more or less the same. A chatroom is where people are supposed to chat, right?

Also, for future reference, if you want to suggest something to the site, don't assume straight away that it's not gonna happen, we hear you!